# I am trying to automate a login form , with the following credentials

Tags: selenium

I am new to automation testing and I am currently trying to automate a login form, user name tomsmith and pass supersecret password

However when i run my below script i only get to the login page,  I am unsure why it is not inputing the details. I also would like to logout automatically as well.

```
package Form;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Authentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        //http://tomsmith:SuperSecretPassword!
        driver.get("http://tomsmith;SuperSecretPassword!@the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");

        String pageMessage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p")).getText();
        System.out.println(pageMessage);
    

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your values to the input tags.

```
driver.findElement(By.ID('username')).sendKeys("tomsmith");
driver.findElement(By.ID('password')).sendKeys("SuperSecretPassword!");
```